# form won't submit correctly via jQuery and reverts to default behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form withthe id offerForm which I submit via Jquery, but despite the 'return false' statement, the form doesn't submit via ajax. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#offerForm').live('submit',function(){   
            loadData(1);

    }); 


    function loadData(page){
                $.post('get-offers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&page=' + page,  function(data) {
        //Do stuff
        $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
               },'json' );
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but you should know that `.live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the ajaxSubmit plugin located here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/. It does exactly what you are trying to do.

In your case, you'd use something like:

```
$('#offerForm').submit(function()
{
    var options = {
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data) {
            $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
        }
    };
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should be stopping the event with `event.preventDefault()` rather than `return false` - they both work, but it's cleaner to use the event.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{      
    $('#offerForm').live('submit',function(event){ // add event as a parameter
        event.preventDefault(); // and call preventDefault here
        loadData(1);
    });

    function loadData(page)
    {
        $.post('get-offers.php', $("#offerForm").serialize() + '&page=' + page,  function(data)
        {
            //Do stuff
            $('#demo').html(data.htmlOutput);
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```